# the infinite series $\sum z^n$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ does not converge uniformly on $|z| <1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

The series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n$ does not converge uniformly on $D(0,1) = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|<1 \}$.
Here is my attempt:

> Suppose to the contrary that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n$ converges uniformly on $D(0,1)$.
> Since uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence, the series converges to
> \begin{equation*}
>     \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}
> \end{equation*}
> for all $z \in D(0, 1)$.
> Choose $z = 1 - \frac{1}{k}$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $z \in D(0, 1)$.
> Then, we have
> \begin{equation*}
>     \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{k}\right)^n = \frac{1}{1 - \left(1 - \frac{1}{k}\right)} = k.
> \end{equation*}
> However, the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{k}\right)^n$ diverges as $k \to \infty$.
> This is a contradiction.

Now I know that I have to use the supremum norm, but why the attempt does not work?

Although the sequence converges to $1$, I thought that it still lives in $D(0,1)$.

---

Edit:

I changed the summation from $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^n$.

Comment: What justification do you have for the claim that the divergence of the sum as $k \to \infty$ implies the sum does not converge uniformly?

Comment: @RobArthan I believe that if the series diverges, then the series cannot be uniformly convergent. But, I think it should be clarified in the proof. If I want to push my argument, what should be added? Thank you.

Comment: Do you know about compactness?

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, a closed and bounded set in $\mathbb{C}$ is compact. Ah, since the sequence is convergent, the limit should live in $D(0,1)$?

Comment: Why not just show it directly using the definition?

Comment: @Eric As I said, I know the proof using the definition is a clear way. The question is to review my attempt to find something that I am missing.

Comment: $\frac1k \neq \frac1n$. The indexing variable is not used in one and is in the other. They are not the same.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Oh I thought that the sequence should not depend on $n$. If I choose $z_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$, is it vaild? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Choosing is to pick a constant and $n$ is an indexing variable. There is no work around since the sum is defined using this variable.

Comment: "However, the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ diverges as $k \to \infty$." There is no $k$ in that series.

Comment: Once you get your notation sorted, showing that the series behaves badly on or in approach to the boundary can be used to prove non-uniform convergence on the open disk.  You need continuity of the functions you are summing on the closed disk -- which you have here with a power series.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I fully understood. I was making a ridiculous claim. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @Gary Ah.. that was a typo, sorry. I revised the question even if CyclotomicField corrected my claim. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @RRL Yes! That was the idea that I wanted to push. But I thought that I was missing something. I think you provided a more detailed answer, so I will continue this discussion with your answer. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the functions $f_n: \overline{D}(0,1) \to \mathbb{C}$ are continuous on the closed disk $\overline{D}(0,1)$ and the series $\sum f_n$ is uniformly convergent on the open disk $D(0,1)$, then the series must be uniformly convergent on the closed disk as well.

From that it follows that the sum $S(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(z)$ is continuous on $\overline{D}(0,1)$. Hence, for any point $z_B$ on the boundary, the limit of $S(z)$ as $z \to z_B$ exists.  Consequently, showing that the limit does not exist or equivalently that the series diverges at $z_B$ is a valid way to prove the series is not uniformly convergent on the open disk.

In this case, the functions $z \mapsto z^n$ are continuous on the closed disk.   Taking the sequence $z_k = (1 - 1/k)$ we have $z_k \to 1 \in \overline{D}(0,1)$ and, as you have shown, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z_k^n $ diverges as $k \to \infty$. Hence, the series $\sum z^n$ cannot be uniformly convergent on $D(0,1)$.

> To prove that the uniform convergence on the open disk implies uniform
> convergence on the closed disk we use the Cauchy criterion.  Denote
> the partial sum as $S_n(z) = \sum_{k=0}^n f_k(z)$.  Uniform
> convergence on $D(0,1)$ means that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists
> $N(\epsilon)$ such that $|S_m(z) - S_n(z)| < \epsilon$ for all $m
>  \geqslant n \geqslant N(\epsilon)$ and for all $z \in D(0,1)$.  Since
> the partial sums are continuous, for any point $z_B$ on the boundary
> we have
>
> $$|S_m(z_B) - S_n(z_B)| = \lim _{z \to z_B}|S_m(z) - S_n(z)| \leqslant
>  \epsilon$$
>
> for all $m\geqslant n \geqslant N(\epsilon)$, which shows that the
> uniform convergence extends to the closed disk.

Comment: There is a tiny typo in $m>\geq n \geq N(\epsilon)$. Now I can see the lack of my argument was the first paragraph you provided. I deeply appreciate your kind answer.

Comment: @himath: You're welcome.